# Space between Thumbnails Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with thumbnails from Bootstrap 3.
I will show you a basic example with thumbnails:

```
<div class="bs-example">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/100%x180" alt="100%x180" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAAC0CAYAAADraNxXAAAFeUlEQVR4Xu3YvUscURiF8buFgtoq2oqtNoIo/vtWKoidWIudrJ0gfiTcCXczTHZmN+menMcqupnsed/z82Z2ZvP5/Efxyw0ANjATK6AlI3YbEKsQMBsQK6Yqg4pVA5gNiBVTlUHFqgHMBsSKqcqgYtUAZgNixVRlULFqALMBsWKqMqhYNYDZgFgxVRlUrBrAbECsmKoMKlYNYDYgVkxVBhWrBjAbECumKoOKVQOYDYgVU5VBxaoBzAbEiqnKoGLVAGYDYsVUZVCxagCzAbFiqjKoWDWA2YBYMVUZVKwawGxArJiqDCpWDWA2IFZMVQYVqwYwGxArpiqDilUDmA2IFVOVQcWqAcwGxIqpyqBi1QBmA2LFVGVQsWoAswGxYqoyqFg1gNmAWDFVGVSsGsBsQKyYqgwqVg1gNiBWTFUGFasGMBsQK6Yqg4pVA5gNiBVTlUHFqgHMBsSKqcqgYtUAZgNixVRlULFqALMBsWKqMqhYNYDZgFgxVRlUrBrAbECsmKoMKlYNYDYgVkxVBhWrBjAbECumKoOKVQOYDYgVU5VBxaoBzAbEiqnKoGLVAGYDYsVUZVCxagCzAbFiqjKoWDWA2YBYMVUZVKwawGxArJiqDCpWDWA2IFZMVQYVqwYwGxArpiqDilUDmA1EY/3+/i7X19fl7e2tXF5elq2trfLw8FCen5//KHB/f7+cnJx0P1923TqNj1339PRUHh8fF//E8fFxOTg46L6fz+fl/v6+e8/61X9tnff8n/5OLNbPz89ydXVVvr6+ymw2W2Dtl7sM1zrXLQMydl37+fb2djk/Py93d3fl9fW1y7OxsdFl7L9Wf7Hq36uvpX1FYu3DqYWPYW2n7OHhYTk6OipT17UTcGdnp8PUrq0n4e7u7uIXY/h+7bq9vb3u5O5f9/Hx0Z247f3bCZx6usZivb29Laenp91J1r8NaKdVg1lPsHaS1Z9NXddOxYuLi3Jzc7M4EaeumzpZX15elmJteD1ZgzYwde85PFVX3R7U11fdIoy939h1wwztZBVrENI26hieVR+gpl6vp2v9r73/gWzq/f7lNkCsYu2eBvRPyPbBZriaMawNXr11eH9//+OT+9TTh+F9af1+c3PTe9be8iPvWVedrMPTbh2sDWJ9unB2dtbdC9c/9z+5L8M6dbK2D2Y+DfjVgFgHz1nrUlbdG/7NCbnO89nhc9b+f/M+Z/19VERjDbzzQY8sVnR9WeHFmtU3elqxouvLCi/WrL7R04oVXV9WeLFm9Y2eVqzo+rLCizWrb/S0YkXXlxVerFl9o6cVK7q+rPBizeobPa1Y0fVlhRdrVt/oacWKri8rvFiz+kZPK1Z0fVnhxZrVN3pasaLrywov1qy+0dOKFV1fVnixZvWNnlas6Pqywos1q2/0tGJF15cVXqxZfaOnFSu6vqzwYs3qGz2tWNH1ZYUXa1bf6GnFiq4vK7xYs/pGTytWdH1Z4cWa1Td6WrGi68sKL9asvtHTihVdX1Z4sWb1jZ5WrOj6ssKLNatv9LRiRdeXFV6sWX2jpxUrur6s8GLN6hs9rVjR9WWFF2tW3+hpxYquLyu8WLP6Rk8rVnR9WeHFmtU3elqxouvLCi/WrL7R04oVXV9WeLFm9Y2eVqzo+rLCizWrb/S0YkXXlxVerFl9o6cVK7q+rPBizeobPa1Y0fVlhRdrVt/oacWKri8rvFiz+kZPK1Z0fVnhxZrVN3pasaLrywov1qy+0dOKFV1fVnixZvWNnlas6Pqywos1q2/0tGJF15cVXqxZfaOnFSu6vqzwYs3qGz2tWNH1ZYUXa1bf6GnFiq4vK7xYs/pGTytWdH1Z4cWa1Td6WrGi68sKL9asvtHTihVdX1b4n4Ds4UXrUfTOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and jsfiddle to it.
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1033/

In this example I want to create thumbnail without space between them , can somebody help me and tell how to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `padding` from `.col-xs-6` and remove the `margin-bottom` from your `a` elements:

```css
.col-xs-6 {
    padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-6 a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/52VtD/1034/).

Answer (score 3):

Its the padding:

```
.col-xs-6 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will fix it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/52VtD/1035/)

***Edit:***

As pointed out in the comments, there was a margin on the bottom of them. This will fix that problem by removing the margin.

```
.col-xs-6 a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/52VtD/1042/)

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue as there's still a big space below each thumbnail on smaller screens.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly If they wanted it like that its now in my answer. (Its always going to be the exactly same as yours so I +1 your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something more like `.no-gutters`. http://julienmelissas.com/no-gutter-column-trick-for-bootstrap/